# iOS Framework relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm doing some image manipulation work in iOS Objective-C and I'm importing the `ImageIO.h` header to give me access to the necessary Quartz 2D stuff. What I'm wondering is although I'm only importing `ImageIO.h` I can use things which are part of `CoreGraphics` like `CGImage` and `CGImageRef`.
Do I not need to import `CoreGraphics.h`? Is one of the frameworks I'm using pulling it in because it relies on it?

I know `ImageIO` used to be part of `CoreGraphics` but I though it was standalone now. FYI I'm also using `Foundation` and (elsewhere) `UIKit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIO.h` includes `ImageIOBase.h`. If you take a look into that file you will find

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

So, if you're including `ImageIO.h` you will always include CoreFoundation and CoreGraphics, too.

Comment: Found the ImageIO header files: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Headers` 
Yes, now I can see how things are getting included. Thanks so much.